# What does “I'm nowhere near ready” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the phrase

> I'm **nowhere near** ready

mean?

For example:

> A:So, are you all packed for your trip?
>
> B:No, I'm **nowhere near** ready.

I know the meaning of nowhere near is *far from; not nearly* but I don't know what *I'm nowhere near ready*
means.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you have all the pieces, if **nowhere near** = **far from**, then **I'm nowhere near ready** = **I'm far from ready/far from being ready**. In other words, he/she is not ready **at all**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "ready" was a place... they're nowhere near it. So, "far from ready" is another idiom that means the same thing - that is, not ready at all.

Answer (score 3):

The word **near**, as you know, is a locative term.  When we say I am **nearly** "ready", there is only the faintest whiff of the locative in the adverb **nearly**. We understand the word abstractly, not in spatial terms, to mean "almost".

However, when we say **I'm nowhere near ready**, there is more than a faint whiff of the locative. "Ready", which is a state, is being cast figuratively as being in a place. Literally, the place where I am is not a location anywhere in the vicinity of readiness.

This is an informal way of saying quite emphatically "I am far from ready".

Answer (score 0):

I means your not ready at all. Your far from being ready or done from whatever you are doing, therefore you are "No where" near being ready. Not even close to finishing.

Comment: I think you mean *you're*.