# "Nowhere near ready/finished" vs "Nowhere near being ready/finished"

Tags: prepositions

I have a quick question.

Which is correct? Are they both correct?

1. I am nowhere near ready.
2. I am nowhere near being ready.

Is "ready" being modified by an adverb in #1?

Please help!

THANKS!

Comment: Both are correct I think. Read this it may help http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/what-does-im-nowhere-near-ready-mean,

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have checked that thread out as well.. but I am still confused!

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here.

First: Yes, both sentences are grammatically correct. But to me, the word "being," in the second sentence, sounds redundant. WIthout the "nowhere near" adverbial phrase, you would say "I am ready."

Second: In both sentences, "nowhere near" is an adverbial phrase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Can adverbial phrases be used for both adjectives and nouns (or noun phrases)?

Comment: Adverbs modify verbs or adjectives (or other adverbs), and so do adverbial phrases.